# Dismiss NSViewController presented with a show segue swift

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift, segue, nsviewcontroller

I have a `NSViewController`, let's name it `SecondViewController` (which is called by the previous `NSViewController`, named `FirstViewController`, as a modal window with a segue) that calls the other `NSViewController`, named `ThirdViewContoller`, with show segue (all segues performed programmatically: `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("nameOfSegue", sender: self)`. When in `SecondViewController` I write this code:

```
self.dismissController(SecondViewContoller)
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("startGame", sender: self)
```

Everything works, but then I need to reopen `SecondViewController` (with a modal segue) using this code in `ThirdViewController`:

```
self.dismissController(ThirdViewController)
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("changeHardness", sender: self)
```

The `ThirdViewController` is never dismissed.

BTW, if I try to open `ThirdViewController` with a modal segue, it crashes, giving that:

> 2015-03-31 11:24:19.429 MiniGames Ultra[8074:522218] *** Assertion
>   failure in                -[Project.SecondViewController
>   presentViewController:animator:],
>   /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1344.72/Controllers/NSViewController.m:803
>   2015-03-31 11:24:19.429 Project[8074:522218]
>   presentViewController:animator:: View '''s view is not in a window/view hierarchy. 2015-03-31
>   11:24:19.431 MiniGames Ultra[8074:522218] (...etc)